# Cannot refer to field class in java

Tags: java, field

I don't know how to solve below problem.
I have got a code like below:

```
public class MyWindow{
    private Button saveButton;
    private Application saveImplementation;
    void createSaveButton() {
        saveButton.addListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
                this.saveImplementation.save();//Cannot resolve symbol 'saveImplementation'
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In saveButton.addListener I cannot refer to saveImplementation, which is a field of class MyWindow - can you help me?
How can I solve it?

Comment: can you also post the error ?

Comment: You need MyWindow.this --- you are inside an **inner** class; so "this" alone points to the "wrong" class.

Comment: And hint: you are grossly overtagging. This has **nothing** todo with field, lambdas, vaadin whatever.

Comment: The error occurs because you have just declare object saveImplementation and not yet instantiate it using new keyword.Just add this line to your 3 line.

 private Application saveImplementation=new Application();

Comment: Ok, thank you I will try to remove this question.

Comment: @javafan Wrong. He is right now dealing with a compilation error. That NullPointerException because not initialized comes later, when he would be able to **run** that code.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the `ClickListener`'s instance. You need to specify the `MyWindow`'s instance via `MyWindow.this.saveImplementation.save();`